# how to solve the slugfield int () problem

Tags: django-models

slugfield does not work the problem is  invalid literal for int() with base 10:
I try all English video and some French video

```
  models
  from django.utils.text import slugify
  class Region(models.Model):
      ...
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
      def __str__(self):
         return self.name

      def _get_unique_slug(self):
         slug = slugify(self.name)
         unique_slug = slug
         num = 1
         while Region.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
         return unique_slug

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.slug:
             self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
         super().save(*args, **kwargs)
urls
path('<region_slug>', views.detail, name='detail'),
views   
def detail(request,region_slug):
    region=get_object_or_404(Region ,pk=region_slug)
          context = {
              .....
              'region_slug':region.slug
          }
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code-formatting

Comment: that's what apparently this error is very common but in the form

Comment: my code is written all that is related to slugfield is written

Comment: I meant the code in the question - the ` from django.utils.text import slugify` is written as text instead of as part of your code. That seems wrong. Could you please [edit] the question and make sure all of the code is formatted correctly?

Comment: in fact I exceeded the number of line of code allow and I wanted to give you all the code so I had to write it like that

Comment: here it is corrected

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly correct because it now has different indentation levels and the class is missing, right?

Comment: now here it is corrected no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in your view. This line points to the primary key (pk) of your model, but the pk isn't the same as the slug. The pk is referencing the auto-inserted `id` field.

```py
def detail(request, region_slug):
    region = get_object_or_404(Region, pk=region_slug)
```

You could make the slug field your primary key, but I would suggest rather pointing to the slug field as it stands now.

```py
def detail(request, region_slug):
    region = get_object_or_404(Region, slug=region_slug)
```